# Creating an If statement with multiple conditions in Power Bi

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with a number of columns. I created a measure that counts how many days its been since the last entry was recorded.

| Location | Days since Last entry |
| --- | --- |
| Book | 10 |
| Hat | 4 |
| Dress | 9 |
| Shoe | 2 |
| Bag | 1 |

I want to create a column that shows the days since the last entry by group. (Red = 9+ days , Amber = 5+&9- days , Green = less than 4 days.

```
So far I tried 

NewColumn= 
    IF (
        [DaysSinceLastEntry] >= 9, "Red",
            IF([DaysSinceLastEntry] < 9 && [DaysSinceLastEntry] >5 = "Amber",)
    &
             IF(
                [DaysSinceLastEntry] <= 5, "Green"
    ))
```

The above gives something like:

| Location | Days since Last entry | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book | 10 | Red |
| Book | 5 | Amber |
| Book | 2 | Green |
| Hat | 9 | Red |
| Hat | 5 | Amber |
| Hat | 2 | Green |

I want:

| Location | Days since Last entry | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book | 10 | Red |
| Hat | 6 | Amber |
| Dress | 9 | Red |
| Shoe | 2 | Green |
| Bag | 1 | Green |

I cant figure out how to display the red/amber/green based on the number of days since the last entry. Doesn't have to be an if statement. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot (from excel or anything) illustrating the expected result please?

Comment: @SamBouKoa Ive added. a table with expected result

Comment: Can you try to create the days since last entry as a column rather than a measure? Then the NewColumn would work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# make dataframe
data = {
    'Location': [
        'Book',
        'Hat',
        'Dress',
        'Shoe',
        'Bag',
    ],
    'DaysSinceLastEntry': [
        10,
        4,
        9,
        2,
        1,
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# assign color
def color_filter(x):
    if x <= 5:
        return '#00FF00' # green
    elif 5 < x <= 9:
        return '#FFBF00' # amber
    else:
        return '#FF0000' # red

df['Color'] = df.DaysSinceLastEntry.map(lambda x: color_filter(x))

# plot
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Bar(x=df['Location'],
           y=df['DaysSinceLastEntry'],
           marker={'color': df['Color']})
)
fig.show()
```